# Cannot change orientation on lollipop

Tags: android, android-orientation

Before lollipop i use

```
        android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"


public void changeFullScreenState(GoFullScreen event){
        if(event.isToFullScreen()){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        } else{
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }
```

to change screen orientation. It worked for api>=15 && api <20. However this does not work on lollipop 5.02
Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What device are you testing at? Some Emulators could give you wrong orientation.